# Excel Timestamp formula = almost working

Tags: excel, date, time, timestamp, formula

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this formula.
I have a spreadsheet with multiple date formulas in it, however, if i change just one cell, all the dates on the sheet change, even if they do not reference the cell that i have actually changed.

```
=IF(C17<>"",IF(D17="",NOW(),D17),"")
```

I have ticked the iterative box as required, and changed maximum to 1000 as it was advised.

As you can see on the screen shot, I have one cell to the left that is stuck at 1900. this one has the same formula, and doesn't actually change when other cells do (i have no idea why, it's the same formula!), however i can't get this one to show today's date.

[image]

Any explanation will be appreciated! But please in simple terms, i'm really not that great with excel.

Comment: Whenever you enter a value in any cell, all cells refresh. As your formula contains `NOW()` , the value will change each time it refreshes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell `D17` is actually '0', but when the same is printed through the formula that you have, it displays as '0' instead of spaces.

The cell seems to formatted as a date and thats the reason why the value shows as `1/0/1900`. You have to alter the formula to prevent this.

`=IF(C17<>"",IF(D17="",NOW(),IF(D17=0,"",D17)),"")`

Answer (score 0):

1/0/1900 is simply the way that Excel displays a date that is zero.

So you can re-check or upload your file for help.

Comment: Hiya, thanks. I managed to get excel to take figures out of the text that was being imported by using the =MID formula.